# Why are the labels for my opposite yaxis in Highcharts not showing up?

Tags: highcharts, axis

I am puzzled why the second yaxis in my Highcharts graph shows, but without any values. Both of my two graphs are still bound to the first yaxis. Can't get one of them attributed to the second yaxis. Here is [a fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/luftikus143/24XAM/2/).

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The charts options are case sensitive. You specified 'yaxis' when it should be 'yAxis'. That took me a while to spot !

```
series: [{
        yAxis: 1,
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    },{
        yAxis: 0,
        data: [19.9, 21.5, 6.4, 29.2, 44.0, 76.0, 35.6, 48.5, 16.4, 94.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
```